# Set downloaded workbook as active workbook which has no fixed name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which will download an excel from website. It works until clicking on open in the website. But the excel file is not getting opened. Also i like to have variable set for the newly downloaded file. Below is the code whcih i have used. It gets struck in `While Workbooks.Count <= w`.

```
Sub download2()

Dim ie As Object
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim downloadBook As Workbook
Dim w As Long
w = Workbooks.Count

Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.Application")
    ie.navigate "https:www.safdsg.com"
    ie.Visible = True

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

    With ie.document

        .getElementById("AJS_DROPDOWN__15").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

        .getElementById("currentExcelFields").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

    End With

SendKeys "%{O}"

While Workbooks.Count <= w
    DoEvents
Wend

Set downloadBook = ActiveWorkbook

MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

Also `Do While ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop` or `Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop` is not working in this code. Hence i have used `application.wait`. Please let me know if anything needs to be added in reference to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it opens by default in the same instance of Excel.Application, it is probably then the `ActiveWorkbook`, or `Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)`, and you can declare a workbook variable and assign from that.

```
Dim downloadBook as Workbook
Dim w as Long
w = Workbooks.Count
' code that downloads the workbook...
' ...
' 
SendKeys "%{O}"
' ## Wait until the new file has opened
While Workbooks.Count < w + 1
    DoEvents
Wend
Set downloadBook = ActiveWorkbook
' OR:
' Set downloadBook = Workbook(w+1)
```

Comment: @Sakthi comments are not the place for code samples. Please edit your question to provide this additional detail/revision attempt.

Comment: It does not look like you're doing what I suggest in my answer. Please try again, and revise your question with an [mcve] otherwise I am not wanting time with you further. Also, don't use Application.Wait, it's notoriously unreliable.

Comment: You will need to provide the URL from which the file is downloaded, otherwise I can't easily assist.

Comment: I notice one problem in my code, try instead: `While Workbooks.Count <= w+1`. We need to `DoEvents` **until** the new book has been opened. Let's try that first.

Comment: Hi @david zemens, I have tried the above code however, excel file is not getting opened. And really sorry that i couldnt provide you the link since it has user specific access.

Comment: Try `While Workbooks.Count < w+1`

Comment: Hello @David Zemens, I have tried the above code as well. But not working as expected. Should i activate excel to open the downloaded file? if yes, can you please provide me the code?

Comment: At this point it is not clear to me what the problem is. You indicate previously that `SendKeys` opens the file. Is that no longer the case, then the scope of your question/problem has changed, and I am not prepared to answer that since you cannot produce [mcve]. If the file is downloaded/opened, then I'm afraid I don't understand what the problem is. You will need to provide more detail about what you mean by "not working as expected". Please revise your question with additional detail(s).

Comment: The workbook is not getting opened until the above code excution goes to End Sub

Comment: That seems impossible, because otherwise you will be in an infinite loop since `Workbooks.Count` will never exceed the value assigned in `w`. Please edit your question to include the code you're currently using. I'm going to be honest here: you seem basically like you have no idea how to debug any of this on your own, and I'm not really interested in pursuing this much further. If you can update your question code, maybe I will see something. But otherwise, since you cannot produce [mcve], there's little more help I may offer anyways.

Comment: Thanks for all your support. I have debugged my code using sleep function after sendkeys .