# How to check if file is already open before proceeding after opening with send keys in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am opening a file from a website. After I send sendkeys "%{O}", I need the file to be opened first before proceeding. If I add wait times or loops after the sendkeys, the file wont open until after those loops. Kindly note that I don't know the name or location of the file, I just opened it from a path given to me.

I have already tried putting Application.Wait, creating a sub that just counts and using this between opening and writing to the worksheet.

```
Application.SendKeys "%{O}" 'opens the workbook from IE
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Needed_Worksheet")
wb2.Cells(1,1) = "HELLO"
```

I expect to write on the first cell of the newly opened workbook.

Comment: Why SendKeys? You can use `Application.Workbooks.Open` if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: Im opening the file from the website. I open it from a given web path and there is a prompt asking if I want to open/save/save as. I sendkeys to open. Do you know of another way to get around this?

Comment: This seems like a nearly exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737827/set-downloaded-workbook-as-active-workbook-which-has-no-fixed-name/56738048?noredirect=1#comment100266529_56738048) which I went round and round on the past few days. If you can't provide an [MCVE], I'm sorry it's not going to be easy to offer much more assistance than what's there already.

Comment: The general idea is to first get a count of how many workbooks are open, and then use a loop until Workbooks.Count = that number + 1 (reflecting the newly opened workbook). From there, I'm not sure if the new book will be Active. if it is, then `ActiveWorkbook` will suffice (though you should assign to a variable if you need to refer to this more than once. If not, then `Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)` should do it, with the same caveat that you really ought assign this to a workbook variable.

Comment: Does Workbooks.Open not support a web address? Maybe you could download the file and then open it directly.

Comment: `Application.Wait` is almost surely the wrong approach, though. `Wait` basically puts the entire Excel Application to sleep. Either a `While` loop with `DoEvents` or calling the WinAPI `Sleep` function would be preferable.

Comment: @JohnWu assuming (like the other question) the *user* is not actually doing this, but rather automating a browser and clicking some link or button that launches the "Save or Download" dialog, which requires `SendKeys` to intercept it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't have the path to the file. I have the path to the webpage that downloads it. The path automatically start the export and I am given a prompt. Thanks for the note about the Application.Wait. I have tried the loop with DoEvents but it's still not opening until the loop is done.

Comment: @DavidZemens This is exactly what im doing thank you.

Comment: *it's still not opening until the loop is done* well of course not. It won't open until the workbook has finished downloading & is open. that's the point of looping until w+1. I'm glad you found a solution, but it would be helpful if you show how you're implementing that in your code. Is it a loop, or just a hard sleep for an arbitrary amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

This is working now using Sleep:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If
```

Then call:

```
Sleep 20000
```

Thanks @DavidZemens for the suggestion